# Google Review slider is not working with owl carousel

Tags: php, jquery, css, google-maps-api-3, owl-carousel

I am trying to make google reviews slider using google API and owl carousel, the problem is that google reviews append data at the very last ( after page completely loaded ), owl carousel function is called before google reviews loaded so owl carousel doesn't work.

I want load google review before owl carousel function called, in order to make slider works fine.

Here is my code segment, top file is for Google Api and below is a simple php template where I use that API code.

```
<?php 
/*
    Configuration.
    Note: You'll need a Google maps API key - requires both Maps JS and Places API services enabled.
*/

$place_ID       = 'ChIJJWZ8calZwokRxvclFn2MzpA'; // Get from: https://developers.google.com/places/place-id
$business_type  = ''; // Example: FinancialService (http://schema.org)
$business_name  = '';
$street_address = '';
$locality       = ''; // Example: Docklands (http://schema.org/addressLocality)
$region         = '';
$post_code      = '';
$logo_path      = 'https://husney.nickpatrocky.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/logo.svg';
$min_star       = '1'; // The minimum star rating (min = 1)
$max_rows       = '5'; // The maximum number of results (max = 5)
$api_key        = 'YOUR_API_KEY';


<script>
(function($) {

$.googlePlaces = function(element, options) {

    var defaults = {
        placeId:        '<?php echo $place_ID; ?>', 
        render:         ['reviews'], 
        min_rating:     <?php echo $min_star; ?>, 
        max_rows:       <?php echo $max_rows; ?>, 
        rotateTime:     false
    };

    var plugin = this;

    plugin.settings = {}

    var $element = $(element),
        element = element;

    plugin.init = function() {
    plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    $element.html("<div id='the-reviews'></div>"); // create a plug for google to load data into
    initialize_place(function(place){
        plugin.place_data = place;
        // render specified sections
        if(plugin.settings.render.indexOf('reviews') > -1){
        renderReviews(plugin.place_data.reviews);
        if(!!plugin.settings.rotateTime) {
            initRotation();
        }
        }
    });
    }

    var initialize_place = function(c){
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('the-reviews'));

    var request = {
        placeId: plugin.settings.placeId
    };

    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        c(place);
        }
    });
    }

    var sort_by_date = function(ray) {
    ray.sort(function(a, b){
        var keyA = new Date(a.time),
        keyB = new Date(b.time);
        // Compare the 2 dates
        if(keyA < keyB) return -1;
        if(keyA > keyB) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
    return ray;
    }

    var filter_minimum_rating = function(reviews){
    for (var i = reviews.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(reviews[i].rating < plugin.settings.min_rating){
            reviews.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    return reviews;
    }

    var renderReviews = function(reviews) {
        reviews = sort_by_date(reviews);
        reviews = filter_minimum_rating(reviews);
        var html = "";
        var row_count = (plugin.settings.max_rows > 0)? plugin.settings.max_rows - 1 : reviews.length - 1;
        // make sure the row_count is not greater than available records
        row_count = (row_count > reviews.length-1)? reviews.length -1 : row_count;
        var counter = 1; var slide = '';
        html = html+"<div class='owl-carousel owl-theme'>"
        for (var i = row_count; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(counter == 1){ slide = 'active'; } else { slide = 'no'; }
            var stars = renderStars(reviews[i].rating);
            var date = convertTime(reviews[i].time);
            html = html+" <div class='item'> testest </div>"
            counter = counter+1;
        };
        html = html+"</div>"
        $element.append(html);
    }
    var initRotation = function() {
        var $reviewEls = $element.children('.review-item');
        var currentIdx = $reviewEls.length > 0 ? 0 : false;
        $reviewEls.hide();
        if(currentIdx !== false) {
            $($reviewEls[currentIdx]).show();
            setInterval(function(){ 
            if(++currentIdx >= $reviewEls.length) {
                currentIdx = 0;
            }
            $reviewEls.hide();
            $($reviewEls[currentIdx]).fadeIn('slow');
            }, plugin.settings.rotateTime);
        }
    }

    var renderStars = function(rating) {
        var stars = "<div class='review-stars' itemprop='reviewRating' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/Rating'><meta itemprop='worstRating' content='1'/><meta itemprop='ratingValue' content='" + rating + "'/><meta itemprop='bestRating' content='5'/><ul>";

        // fill in gold stars
        for (var i = 0; i < rating; i++) {
            stars = stars+"<li class='star'>&#9733;</li>";
        };

        // fill in empty stars
        if(rating < 5){
            for (var i = 0; i < (5 - rating); i++) {
                stars = stars+"<li class='star inactive'>&#9733;</li>";
            };
        }
        stars = stars+"</ul></div>";
        return stars;
    }

    var convertTime = function(UNIX_timestamp) {
        var a = new Date(UNIX_timestamp * 1000);
        var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
        var time = months[a.getMonth()] + ' ' + a.getDate() + ', ' + a.getFullYear();
        return time;
    }

    plugin.init();

}

$.fn.googlePlaces = function(options) {

    return this.each(function() {
    if (undefined == $(this).data('googlePlaces')) {
        var plugin = new $.googlePlaces(this, options);
        $(this).data('googlePlaces', plugin);
    }
    });

}

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I've removed your API key from your question. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your plugin init with a setTimeout, delay its execution by x seconds to give the Places API call enough time to consume the data; unsure how much lag you have before the data comes in but suppose you want to delay by 4 seconds;

```
setTimeout(Function(){
    plugin.init = function() {
    plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    $element.html("<div id='the-reviews'></div>"); // create a plug for google to load data into
    initialize_place(function(place){
        plugin.place_data = place;
        // render specified sections
        if(plugin.settings.render.indexOf('reviews') > -1){
        renderReviews(plugin.place_data.reviews);
        if(!!plugin.settings.rotateTime) {
            initRotation();
        }
        }
    });
    }
}, 4000);
```

All were doing is just telling the plugin init to wait; in theory this should work :)